# Dialog box doen't occupy entire width of a browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a dialog box which confirms ok or cancel.
The width of the dialog box is already 100% ie `width:100%`, but it still doesn't occupy entire width of the browser.
a backdrop occupies entire width though.

//App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ConfirmationDialog from "./ConfirmationDialog";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setConfirm(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setConfirm(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
      <ConfirmationDialog open={confirm} handleClose={handleClose} />
    </>
  );
}
```

// ConfirmationDialog.js

```js
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";

function ConfirmationDialogRaw(props) {
  const { onClose, open, ...other } = props;
  const handleCancel = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      sx={{ "& .MuiDialog-paper": { width: "100%", maxHeight: 435 } }} // This only occupies middle part of the browser, left and right side backdrop is visible.
      maxWidth="xs"
      open={open}
      {...other}
    >
      <DialogTitle>Dialog Title</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent dividers>Hello World!</DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button autoFocus onClick={handleCancel}>
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleOk}>Ok</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

function ConfirmationDialog({ open, handleClose }) {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 400, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
      <ConfirmationDialogRaw
        id="confirmationId"
        keepMounted
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
export default ConfirmationDialog;
```

How to occupy entire browser width with the dialog box?

[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/increase-mui-dialog-size-2se8yc) Demo

Answer (score 0):

the maxWidth property is the problem

```
  return (
    <Dialog
      sx={{ "& .MuiDialog-paper": { width: "100%", maxHeight: 435 } }} // This only occupies middle part of the browser, left and right side backdrop is visible.
      maxWidth="xs"
      open={open}
      {...other}
    >
```

remove

```
maxWidth="xs"
```

The rest not ocuppyed by the dialog it's the dialog margin